# Play sound in background thread issue

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I have an app that in an activity i do heavy animations and play sound i used the below code to play the sound

```
var musicThread:Thread? = null

fun playSound(sound:Uri) {

    musicThread =  Thread(Runnable {
            try {

                sharedPlayer.reset()
                sharedPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MyApplication.appContext,sound)
                sharedPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                //  sharedPlayer.prepare()
                sharedPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f)
                sharedPlayer.setLooping(false)
                sharedPlayer.start()
                sharedPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
                    it.reset()
                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

           runOnUiThread {


           }

    })

    musicThread?.start()



}
fun stopSound() {
    try {

        if (sharedPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            sharedPlayer.stop()
        }

        musicThread?.stop()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Is there any problem with it ?  BTW i call playSound many times with different sound files one by one

Comment: You don't need to set up a thread for MediaPlayer. It handles that under the hood so you can call all its public functions from the UI thread without issue, with the exception of `prepare()` since it is blocking.

Comment: @Tenfour04 the is `prepareAsync()` which also handles preparing under the hood , and we can listen when the preparation gets completed